# Proof of the median, mean, and mode for frequency distribution table

Tags: statistics

I was wondering is there a proof (or at least an Idea behind them) for the formula for the mean, median, and mode given a frequency distribution table.

The formula looks like this (the one I learn from my high-school):

mean = $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}f_ix_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}f_i}$,  where $f_i$is the frequency for each class and $x_i$ is the midpoint of each class

median = $L_1+\left( \frac{\frac{N}{2}-(\sum f)_l}{f_{median}} \right)c$, where $L_1$ is the lower class boundary of the median class, N is the total frequency, ($\sum f$) is the sum of frequency of all classes lower than the median class, $f_{median}$ is the frequency of the median class, and $c$ is the size of the median class

mode= $L_1+\left(\frac{\Delta_1}{\Delta_2+\Delta_1}\right)c$, where $L_1$ is the lower class boundary of the modal class (the class containing the mode), $\Delta_1$ is the excess of modal frequency over frequency of next-lower class, $\Delta_2$ is the  excess of modal frequency over frequency of next-higher class.